# Pre-fill new email with user location

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send an email to a user. When the user clicks a link on the email it should open a new email with his current location (latitude and longitude) in the email. I have not scripted anything on it. Any idea on how I should proceed to get user location from a link in email will be helpful.

Comment: Probably this link will be helpful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an easyest way to send the email (no SMTP or third party APIs involved), consider using [mailto:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) scheme.